# Cast a column into specific datatype based on string value in another column BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I am looking to change the data type of one column into the datatype placed as a string in another column on BigQuery.

E.g. I have two columns, value and datatype, both currently strings, where the datatype column contains 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'FLOAT64'. I want to do something like

SELECT
SAFE_CAST(value AS datatype)
FROM table.

is there any way to do this?

I have tried directly casting but I get the error can't find the type 'datatype'. I have also tried explicitly using a UDF and CASE statements, but it requires me to return the same datatype from all CASE STATEMENTS, same issue when using IF statements.